# Visual Studio Failing to Create New Android Device

Tags: android, visual-studio, maui, android-device-manager

I'm new to mobile development and I wanted to have a go with MAUI to start learning a bit. I followed all the instructions and I ran `maui-check` which says everything's fine, apart not finding any android emulator. Here's the result:
[image]

I then went to Visual Studio (both 2019 and 2022) trying to create a new Android device (following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows)) to see if then my HelloMaui project was debugging, but that's where I'm hitting a snag.

I set up all needed packages in the Android SDK Manager and I think that's looking good:
[image]
[image]

But then when I try to create a new Android device through the Android Device Manager I always get this error:
[image]

This is my JDK location though:
[image]

Can anyone help? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: MAUI is still in pre-release and may not be a good option for learning mobile development.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but I've seen a few presentations and it looks very interesting so I thought I'd give it a go. I'm reluctant to give up just because I cannot create an Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, is Hypervisor Support enabled on Intel, or SVN enabled on AMD? I had an issue very similar to this, and that is all it was.

Comment: Yeah Hyper-V and Hypervisor are enabled but still not working...

Comment: Have you tried Android Studio to run your AVD's? That is the only other thing worth trying, to determine whether it is a buggy JDK install etc etc.

Comment: Nope I actually haven't. I'm gonna give it a go now. Should I just install and try to create a device?

Comment: Yeah give it a shot, if you get an error creating an AVD in Android Studio, that narrows down the issue and you should be able to pull an error log.

Comment: So I managed to create a device with Android Studio and I can start it without issues. Visual Studio still doesn't want to create one though

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem, I solved it by installing the JDK I downloaded from the [Oracle Website](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html).

After installing it, Open Visual Studio, Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings > Java Development Kit Location: change the location to C:\Program Files\Java[The version of JDK you just installed, jdk1.8.0_301 in my case].

From there all went well for me.